# Просмотр группы "Администраторы" на компьютере через Powershell

Tags: powershell

В интернете нашел код, получить всех пользователей всех групп компьютера.

```
$computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$cmp,computer" 

$list=@()

$computer.psbase.children | where { $_.psbase.schemaClassName -eq 'group' } | foreach {
    $group =[ADSI]$_.psbase.Path
    $group.psbase.Invoke("Members") | foreach {
        $us = $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
        $list += new-object psobject -property @{Group = $group.Name;User=$us}
    }
}
```

Такой вопрос. Где в коде добавить, что нужно получить информацию не со всех групп ,а только с группы "Администраторы". Спасибо

Comment: замените на `$group = [ADSI]$_.psbase.children.find(”Administrators”)`

Comment: Принципиально через Powershell? Чем не угодил `net localgroup Administrators`?

Answer (score 0):

Например, можно воспользоваться WMI. Вот так:

```
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$GroupName = 'Администраторы'
$Query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_GroupUser WHERE GroupComponent=""Win32_Group.Domain='{0}',Name='{1}'""" -f $ComputerName, $GroupName
$GroupUsers = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName -Query $Query
foreach ($User in $GroupUsers){$User.PartComponent.Substring($User.PartComponent.IndexOf(',') + 1) -replace 'Name=' -replace [Char]34}
```

Answer (score 0):

В связи с тем, что работе зоопарк из русских и английских версий, написал себе вот аткую функцию, которая группу определяет на основе well known SID, а не по названию.

```
Function Get-LocalAdminsMember{
Param(
    [string]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
)
$obj = [ADSI]"WinNT://$ComputerName"
$GroupSid = 'S-1-5-32-544'
$AdminGroupSid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($GroupSid)
$AdminGroupName = $AdminGroupSid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value -replace '.+\\'
if ($obj){
    $admingroup = $obj.Children |  Where-Object {$_.name -eq $AdminGroupName}
    if ($admingroup){
        $AdminGroupName = $admingroup | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
        $members = $admingroup.Invoke('Members') 
        if ($Members){
            Foreach ($Member in $Members){
                $Account = Get-GroupMember -Member $Member -ComputerName $ComputerName
                if ($Account){
                    $account | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name GroupName -Value $AdminGroupName
                    $Accounts += @($Account)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
Return $Accounts
}
Function Get-GroupMember{
Param (
    $Member,
    $ComputerName
    )
    $AdsPath=$member.GetType().Invokemember("ADSPath","GetProperty",$null,$member,$null)
    $domain=($AdsPath -split '/')[-2]
    $SamAccountName=($AdsPath -split '/')[-1]
    if($domain -eq $Computername){
        $accounttype='Local'
    }else{
        $accounttype='Domain'
    }
    $objectsid = $member.GetType().Invokemember("objectsid","GetProperty",$null,$member,$null)
    $sid = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new($objectsid,0).value
    $Account = [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = $SamAccountName
        SID = $sid
        Class=$member.GetType().Invokemember("Class","GetProperty",$null,$member,$null)
        AccountType=$accounttype
        ComputerName = $computername
        
    }
    if ($Account){
        Return $Account 
    }

 }
Get-LocalAdminsMember
```

А так начиная с powershell версии 5.1 есть командлет **Get-LocalGroupMember**